# How to enable drag files into whole form on c#?

Tags: c#, forms, drag-and-drop, treelistview

I have a windows form, into which I want to enable drag & drop attachments.

I've activated myForm_DragEnter and myForm_DragDrop events and it seems to work.

However, In one place (treeListView), I can't perform the drag action.

How can I resolve this issue? I don't want to enable dragging into the treeListView, but to the form...

Answer (score 1):

Enable dragging into the treeListView and send the dragged item to the form. 
Send a reference of Form to the treeListView or simple call directly Form's drag function.

Comment: Hmm... apparently my treeListView has drag&drop events of its own (to enable reordering its rows). disabling those events cause the form drag to work, but I don't want to disable it... how can I save both?

Comment: dont disable it, just call the Form's drag&drop event-callback function inside the treeListView's drag&rop event-callback function